# How can I sanitize this URL for an embedded webpage in an Ionic 3 page?

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3

I have a page in ionic 3, that has an embedded webpage in it.

```
ionic (Ionic CLI) : 3.9.2
Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.9.2
```

I'd like to pass the URL into it instead of hard coding it as I've done here:

```
//myPage.html
<ion-header>
</ion-header>

<ion-content padding>
    <iframe class='webPage' name="samplePage" src="https://www.example.com">
    </iframe>
</ion-content>
```

However, all the methods I've tried end up with the same result. And error complaining that the URL is not safe

```
ERROR Error: Required a safe ResourceURL, got a URL (see http://g.co/ng/security#xss)
at DomSanitizerImpl.checkNotSafeValue (platform-browser.js:4523)
at DomSanitizerImpl.sanitize (platform-browser.js:4505)
at setElementProperty (core.js:10795)
at checkAndUpdateElementValue (core.js:10715)
at checkAndUpdateElementInline (core.js:10649)
at checkAndUpdateNodeInline (core.js:13931)
at checkAndUpdateNode (core.js:13878)
at debugCheckAndUpdateNode (core.js:14771)
at debugCheckRenderNodeFn (core.js:14750)
at Object.eval [as updateRenderer] (myPage.html:line#)
```

Or something similar along that theme.

I've tried calling a function that returns a sanitize copy of the URL.

```
// myPage.html
<ion-content padding>
    <iframe [class]="webPage" [name]="samplePage" [src]="getSafeSupportURL()">
    </iframe>
</ion-content>

//myPage.ts
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPage, NavController, NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';
import { DomSanitizer, SafeUrl } from "@angular/platform-browser";

@IonicPage()
@Component({
  selector: 'page-websupport',
  templateUrl: 'myPage.html',
})
export class WebsupportPage {

  cleanSupportURL: any;

  constructor(public navController: NavController, 
      public navParams: NavParams, 
      private sanitizer: DomSanitizer) {
  }

  getSafeSupportURL():SafeUrl {
      return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustUrl('https://example.com'); 
  }

  ionViewDidLoad() {
  console.log('ionViewDidLoad WebsupportPage');
  }

}
```

I've tried creating a sanitized variable and referencing that in the HTML

```
// myPage.html
//...
<ion-content padding>
    <iframe [class]="webPage" [name]="samplePage" [src]={{cleanSupportURL}}>
    </iframe>
</ion-content>

//myPage.ts
//...
cleanSupportURL: any;

constructor(public navController: NavController, 
    public navParams: NavParams, 
    private sanitizer: DomSanitizer) {
  this.cleanSupportURL = 
      this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustUrl('https://example.com');
      // also tried bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl
}
```

I've even tried sanitizing it in the HTML

```
// myPage.html
//...
<ion-content padding>
    <iframe [class]="webPage" 
            [name]="samplePage" 
            [src]="sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl{{myURL}}">
    </iframe>
</ion-content>

//myPage.ts
//...
myURL: any;

constructor(public navController: NavController, 
    public navParams: NavParams, 
    private sanitizer: DomSanitizer) {
   this.myURL = 'https://example.com';
}
```

Any idea how I can get around this very helpful security?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will give you a solution for second method you have tried which is **creating a sanitized variable and referencing that in the HTML**.

**Change your myPage.html as below.**

```
<ion-content padding>
    <iframe [class]="webPage" [name]="samplePage" [src]="cleanSupportURL">
    </iframe>
</ion-content>
```

**Change your MyPage.ts as below.**

```
import { DomSanitizer } from "@angular/platform-browser";

export class MyPage {

    private cleanSupportURL: any;
    sanitizer: DomSanitizer;
    url: string = "https://example.com";

    constructor(sanitizer: DomSanitizer) {

        this.sanitizer = sanitizer;
        this.cleanSupportURL = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(this.url);
    }

}
```

Try above changes and It will work.

Comment: Much better... its working for me now. What's the secret sauce? Is it passing the URL as an string instead of the sting-constant?

Comment: If this answer worked for you, please mark the answer

Comment: Opps thought I had ... sorry